# Build expired when creating pull request

Tags: tfs, pull-request

In simple words please,
What is the meaning of "build expired" when creating a pull request?
All answers I found are the same, from microsoft website.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What tool or service are you working with that gives you this problem? Please provide as many information as you can when asking a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the meaning of "build expired" when creating a pull request?

"Build Expired" is a feature of branch policies. Set a build expiration to make sure that updates to your protected branch don't break changes in open pull requests.

In short, when the target branch is updated before the pull request is completed, build expiration will be triggered.

For example:

Pull Request: Release -> Master. Master branch have other new changes during the Pull Request Process. It will trigger the Build expiration.

You can set the expiration time according to your needs:

1. Immediately when branch is updated.
2. After n hours if branch  has been updated
3. Never

You can navigate to `Repos -> Branches -> Branch Policy -> Build validation` to check the detailed settings.

[image]

> Build expired when creating pull request

From you situation, you may have set the first policy: `Immediately when branch is updated`.

When you see the build expired, this means that the target branch has some new changes.

To solve this issue, you can choose a suitable policy for build expiration.

Here is the doc about [branch policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops#build-validation).

Comment: Excellent explanation! Thank you!!